# Get stock quotes from yahoo finance in json format using a javascript

Tags: javascript, rest

I was trying to get stock quotes from yahoo api.
My input to the query is only a stock ticker ( from a text field). On button click the background JavaScript method "getprice()" is called.
I have a java script code that looks like this

```
function getprice()
{
    var symbol = $('#stockquote').val();


    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22"+symbol+"%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json";

    $.getJSON(url, function (json)
    {

        var lastquote = json.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
        $('#stock').text(lastquote);

    });
}

 $('#stock').text(lastquote);
```

Here "stock" is the text field where I want to display the LastTradePriceOnly for the given ticker.

I do not see any output turning up. 
Debugging also does not show up any errors.
Can I get any suggestions with this issue?

Comment: Unless you host your JavaScript on yahooapis.com domain you won't be able to get JSON due to origin restriction.

Comment: You could also try to use a library that provides the stock market API, so you don't have to implement it yourself. Have a look at [stocks.js](https://github.com/wagenaartje/stocks.js)

Answer (score 13):

Try this.

```
function getData() {
    var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
    var symbol = $("#symbol").val();
    var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + symbol + "')");

    $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env")
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#result').text("Price: " + data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
        })
        .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log('Request failed: ' + err);
        });
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vlad_bezden/RU8Jq/) I also added working example for you.

Comment: @vladbezden How would you implement this for a query that uses more than one symbol?

Comment: @MichaelRamos, you can use the same code to in order to get more than one symbol. Just send comma separated list of symbols ('MSFT, IBM') to query, and now your data.query.results.quote object will have two objects information in it one for MSFT and second one for IBM. You can find what security that object is about by data.query.results.quote[0].symbol will return 'MSFT' and data.query.results.quote[1].symbol will return 'IBM'

Comment: I implemented this code + jquery cookie plugin for caching on a site recently, works great.

Comment: API seems to be outdated. does not work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it's done in AngularJS in case you need it:

In your view:

```
<section ng-controller='StockQuote'>
    <span>Last Quote: {{lang}}, {{lastTradeDate}}, {{lastTradeTime}}, {{lastTradePriceOnly}}</span>
</section><br>
```

In your controller: The stock symbol name is passed via $scope.ticker_name to service method 'getData.getStockQuote'.

```
appModule.controller('StockQuote', ['$scope', 'getData',
function($scope, getData) {
    var api = getData.getStockQuote($scope.ticker_name);
    var data = api.get({symbol:$scope.ticker_name}, function() {
        var quote = data.query.results.quote;
        $scope.lang = data.query.lang;
        $scope.lastTradeDate = quote.LastTradeDate;
        $scope.lastTradeTime = quote.LastTradeTime;
        $scope.lastTradePriceOnly = quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
    });
}]);
```

In your service:

```
appModule.service('getData', ['$http', '$resource', function($http, $resource) {
    // This service method is not used in this example.
    this.getJSON = function(filename) {
        return $http.get(filename);
    };
    // The complete url is from https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/.
    this.getStockQuote = function(ticker) {
        var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
        var data = encodeURIComponent(
            "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + ticker + "')");
        url += '?q=' + data + '&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';
        return $resource(url);
    }
}]);
```